# BeanCreationException after upgrading to spring boot parent version 3.2.0 from 3.1.5

Tags: java, spring-boot

my application was on `spring boot 3.1.5` and working perfetctly, After the release of `spring boot parent version 3.2.0`, it has beeen upgraded. the pom file is as below

```xml
    org.springframework.boot
    spring-boot-starter-parent
    3.2.0
     <!-- lookup parent from repository  -->
```

But then while starting the server, it started throwing error like as below:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/ingka/rc/kommunicera/config/SecurityConfig.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Invalid authentication path
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1651)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeanCollection(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:872)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]: Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message: Invalid authentication path
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Tried with adding below in `pom.xml` as suggested on the migration guide:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2-Release-Notes#upgrading-from-spring-boot-31

```xml
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository  -->
  </parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like our version of Spring Cloud (2022.0.4) and Spring Cloud GCP (4.8.4) is not yet compatible with Spring Boot 3.2.0 so I think we should hold off with upgrading (and even consider reverting for Konsumera's). https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud
[8:32 PM] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/issues/2301
spring.iospring.io
Spring Cloud
Level up your Java code and explore what Spring can do for you. (9 kB)
https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

#2301 Compatibility with upcoming Spring Boot 3.2 / Spring Cloud 2023.0
Compatibility with Spring Project Versions currently shows that Spring Cloud GCP 4.x is compatible with Spring Boot 3.x.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).